# SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"); customize the timezone

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, formatter

I want to print the date with the char `":"` in the middle of timezone,
example :

```
2023-08-02T14:19:10+02:00
```

At the moment I am using this pattern:

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
```

and it prints:

```
2023-08-02T14:19:10+0200
```

Any idea?

below an example of code :

```java
public class testDate {

    public static final DateFormat PATTERN = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

    public static String calendarToString(final Calendar dateToConvert, final DateFormat df) {
        return df.format(dateToConvert.getTime());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar effectiveDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(calendarToString(effectiveDate, PATTERN));
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop using outdated classes like `SimpleDateFormat`. move to the newer `java.time` API

Comment: Please share an [MCVE]

Comment: By what time zone are you expecting an offset of +02:00?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you don’t use `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes were poorly designed, troublesome and cumbersome to work with. Fortunately they are long outdated. Use `OffsetDateTime` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) for an easier job and fewer unpleasant surprises. See [the good answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76823909/5772882).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `XXX` instead of `Z` to get a timezone formatted as `{Z|{+|-}HH:mm}`. That said, you should really switch to using the new `java.time` types, and stop using `SimpleDateFormat`.

This is shown in one of the examples in the [`SimpleDateFormat` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> | Date and Time Pattern | Result |
> | --- | --- |
> | ... | ... |
> | `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"` | `2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00` |

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with Java 1.8+, you should use classes from the `java.time` package.

The format you use for the `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class should also work with the `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` class.

Here is an example:

```java
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class ZonedDateTimeFormatExample {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Africa/Cairo"));
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    System.out.printf("Current date and time in Cairo, Egypt: %s%n", fmt.format(now));
  }
}
```

---

Avoid using the `java.text` and `java.util` packages for date/time/calendar parsing and formatting.

This includes, but is not limited to:

- `java.util.Calendar`
- `java.util.Date`
- `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`

Please review: [Java SE 8 Date and Time](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

- You are working too hard.
- Use modern *java.time*. Never use `Calendar` & `SimpleDateFormat`.
- No need to specify a formatting pattern for standard format.
- Truncate your unwanted fractional second.

```java
OffsetDateTime.now().truncatedTo( SECONDS ).toString()
```

> 2023-08-02T14:19:10+02:00

## `java.time.OffsetDateTime`

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

For a date with time-of-day in the context of an offset-from-UTC, use the class [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

First specify your desired [offset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html).

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( 2 ) ;  // +02:00
```

Capture the [current moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#now(java.time.ZoneId)) as seen in that offset.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( offset ) ;
```

Since you have no interest in the fractional second, [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = odt.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

Generate text in your desired format which happens to comply with the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats used by default in *java.time* when generating/parsing text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String output = odt.toString() ;
```

> 2023-08-02T14:19:10+02:00

Rather than hard-code an offset, you may want to specify a time zone to automatically determine the offset in effect at that point in time.

```
String output = 
    ZonedDateTime
    .now(
        ZoneId.of( "Africa/Gaborone" ) 
    )
    .toOffsetDateTime()
    .truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS )
    .toString()
;
```

Comment: Good and knowledgeable answer. `OffsetDateTime.now()` conveniently accepts a `ZoneId` (not just a `ZoneOffset`). So in your last snippet you can advantageously use `OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Gaborone" ) )`, and you will not need the conversion.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yours is a clever solution. But I might prefer the longer solution with an intermediary of `ZonedDateTime` to make clear my intention. But then this is actually a moot issue as I cannot imagine a situation where I would  prefer having a `OffsetDateTime` rather than a `ZonedDateTime` as a final result.

Comment: Right. In most real-world programs we would not be satisfied with a string, but would want the date-time object, and then `ZonedDateTime` is the most appropriate type when we got it as the current time in some time zone. A third option would be truncating  the `ZonedDateTime` and formatting it using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`. Which to prefer depends on circumstances (and taste).